# Is it possible to install spinnaker without redis?

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I want to install a spinnaker without redis! Is it possible?
I will be using GCS for persistent storage.
I have managed to set up Orca,Front50, Clouddriver to use SQl as described  [here](https://spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/persistence/orca-sql/) , [here](https://spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/persistence/clouddriver-sql/) and [here](https://spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/persistence/front50-sql/) .

If all these microservices are using SQL as backend, why Redis is being installed automatically?
Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is used as persistent cache across multiple services. It is a hard dependency.

try [externalising your redis](https://spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/caching/externalize-redis/) or use an internal redis as the [helm chart deployment](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/spinnaker/values.yaml#L244-L246) does.